# How to do AWS CloudFront distribution Clone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution which have custom origin for my API. I will clone the same API for different clients. Is there any way to clone the CloudFront distribution? This will help me to minimize the time of creating all the behaviors once again for my new partner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way to do it with the console at the moment.
You can dump the existing configuration with the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/get-distribution-config.html), edit it, then create the new distribution.

Comment: You mean, I have to edit the configuration (JSON) file and create a new distribution using [create-distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-distribution.html)

Comment: Yes, get the distribution configuration, edit the config, then create the distribution

Comment: Someone made a helpful guide for doing this here: https://chrisbitting.com/2019/12/31/cloning-an-aws-cloudfront-distribution-easily/